# Powershell String search

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search a keyword/pattern match in a file, where the lines will be starting with date.
Line will be like below

```
11/02/15 02:28:49%%PROGRAM$$SUCCESS$$End.
```

So i tried with below command,

```
Select-String -Path C:\Path\To\File.txt -Pattern $(Get-Date -format d) | Select-String -Pattern SUCCESS
```

So that i can get lines which contain `SUCCESS` with a starting of current date.

Its working on my test box and when i tried the same on a big file (~200 MB), its not giving any results. Tried below too,

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Path\To\File.txt | Select-String -Pattern $(Get-Date -format d) | Select-String -Pattern SUCCESS
```

Any help any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On my PC `Get-Date -format d` return `02.11.2015`. Do you have any line in your file matching this? *Note: `.` is special character for regular expression and will match any one character.*

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider here. As PetSerAl brings to light, `Get-Date -Format d` depends on the culture, so you need to be careful about relying on the output of that.

If the files you're searching are generated using `Get-Date -Format d` then it makes sense to do the search that way as long as the files will always be searched on a machine with the same culture they were generated with.

By the way on my machine it's `11/2/2015` not `11/02/15` and I am in the US.

Also, when you use `Select-String -Pattern` it's a regular expression, so you need to make sure that there are no special characters in the string. In the case of PetSerAl's date, the dots `.` would be interpreted as special characters. To avoid that use `[RegEx]::Escape()`.

`Select-String` returns a match object (or objects), so piping it directly into another `Select-String` may not work. Consider making a single pattern out of it.

Just a guess here, but it kind of seems like the pattern you want is to match the current date string at the beginning of the line and then find `SUCCESS` anywhere after that in the line.

I think for that you could use a pattern like this: `11/02/15.+?SUCCESS`

So code like this:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Path\To\File.txt | Select-String -Pattern "$([RegEx]::Escape((Get-Date -Format d))).+?SUCCESS"
```

Would do the trick I think, again assuming culture issues don't mess you up.